# Red Circle Icon with horizontal white line icon , and terminal won't open

Tags: command-line

I have installed alot of apps and I really don't know which one of them caused the issue , 
I receive this message if I click in the red circle :
A problem occurred when checking for updates , and a lot of options which none of them actually work,

and the terminal won't open by any mean

Comment: Check what apps are in Startup applications.

Comment: thank you , there are only two apps in startup applications im-launch and SSH Key Agent , should I remove them ?

Comment: Try with im-launch.

Comment: still nothing I think its related to the python version

Comment: My idea is to check running processes using `ps aux` or `top` and kill what would seem to be the culprit.

Comment: Not even ctrl+alt+f1?